# Ruby on Rails. Uninitialized constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave

This is odd, but:

Uploader class (app/uploaders):

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::RMagick

  # ....

  version :thumb, from_version: :preview do
    process resize_to_limit: [Image::THUMB_WIDTH]
  end
```

Image class (app/models):

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader

  THUMB_WIDTH = 220
  PREVIEW_WIDTH = 460
  MAX_WIDTH = 960
```

The application says:

`uninitialized constant Image::THUMB_WIDTH`

```
  version :thumb, from_version: :preview do
    process resize_to_limit: [Image::THUMB_WIDTH] #<<<----
  end

  version :preview, from_version: :fullsize do
```

What's wrong?

UPDATE:

Agis pointed out the reason.

Bounty for the best solution to this problem will be applied in 2 days. I don't like code separation, e.g. making a new class holding all the constants for the Image class in initializers etc. This solutions is bad because it it brings inconsistency and code fragmentation.

Comment: try this `version :thumb, from_version: :preview { process resize_to_limit: [Image::THUMB_WIDTH] }` and say answer =)

Comment: `unexpected '{', expecting keyword_end`

Comment: try fixed `version( :thumb, from_version: :preview ) { process resize_to_limit: [Image::THUMB_WIDTH] }` and say answer =)

Comment: Put tht definition of `THUMB_WIDTH = 220` before the mounting `mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader`, we'll see that it be.

Comment: At the point you call mount_uploader the constant is not defined yet. Moving the constant definition before the mount call will solve the issue.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### A general answer

You have a chicken or egg case as far as rails autoloader is concerned, the "rails way" of solving this in a general sense would be to refactor the metacode so that the class names get passed as string values rather than classes, for example:

```
belongs_to :manager, class_name: "Employee"
```

`belongs_to` will call `constantize` on `class_name` hopefully at a time when all classes have been loaded so the chicken and egg issue is circumvented "the rails way".

What **@Stoic** suggested is essentially a variation of this theme of circumventing the evaluation of `image.rb` at `image_uploader.rb` load time:

```
model.class.const_get("THUMB_WIDTH")
```

could also have been phrased as:

```
'Image'.constantize.const_get("THUMB_WIDTH")
```

and result is the same and the general lesson to take from this is: **avoid using another class name literals in class load-time code** or in other words `belongs_to :manager, class_name: "Employee"` is good and `belongs_to :manager, class_name: Employee` would be bad.

It's not pretty, but its probably the most elegant universal way to avoid these headaches

---

### A problem specific answer

A different way of looking at the problem is that thumbnail icon width is actually **a concern of the uploader** and not of the model and that you're in fact seeing a fringe case of inappropriate intimacy code smell (http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/05/code-smells.html).

> Watch out for classes that spend too much time together, or classes that interface in inappropriate ways. Classes should know as little as possible about each other.

So, if you are of this school of thought (I'm leaning in this direction) the solution would be to make `THUMB_WIDTH` a constant of the `ImageUploader` class and the problem goes away.

It's generally a good idea to separate different domain concerns out of the models anyway as the models like to get bloated and unmanageable - you could view the uploader class as a service class of your model designed to extract a particular domain problem much in the same way value objects, form objects etc get handled in http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2012/10/17/7-ways-to-decompose-fat-activerecord-models/

---

Plan C would be to switch places of `config.autoload_paths` in your `application.rb` and cross fingers :)

Comment: A very thorough answer, a lot of useful information, good references. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

This happens because the code for the `ImageUploader` class is evaluated *before* the one for the `Image` class. So at the point where `Image::THUMB_WIDTH` is evaluated, the constant lookup happens and searches for the `Image` constant but does not find it since the relevant file is not loaded yet.

You can fix this by adding this definition at the top of  your `ImageUploader` file:

```
class Image; end
```

You could also do the same but in an initializer instead (ex. `config/initializers/image.rb`).

This would make sure that the `Image` class is loaded at the beginning of the boot process, before everything else and may be considered a clearer solution to you in case you don't want to have definitions of different classes in the same file.

Comment: I do like what you have stated (as I was naive not to think of that :P ), but the only problem with this method is that we will have to do this for every model we want this uploader to handle, IMHO.

Answer (score 3):

I think you should probably move the constants out of the class, and into the wider namespace in an initializer. Or you could create a method on the image class to access the constant instead. This may or may not alleviate your problems.

```
class Image
  THUMB_WIDTH = 220

  def self.thumb_width
    THUMB_WIDTH
  end
end

process resize_to_limit: [Image.thumb_width]
```

Answer (score 2):

Rails provides a convenient place to store configuration data: `Rails.application.config`. This will solve your dependency problem and nicely separate the configuration from the logic. I know you said you prefer not to separate them, but I think this is pretty clean (better than creating a constants module).

In config/application.rb:

```
config.image_sizes = {
  thumb_width: 220,
  preview_width: 460,
  max_width: 960,
}.with_indifferent_access
```

In app/uploaders/image_uploader.rb:

```
version :thumb, from_version: :preview do
  process resize_to_limit: [Rails.application.config.image_sizes[:thumb_width]]
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `ImageUploader` class is being autoloaded before `THUMB_WIDTH` has been defined. Change the definition order:

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

  THUMB_WIDTH = 220
  PREVIEW_WIDTH = 460
  MAX_WIDTH = 960

  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader

end
```

Comment: interpreters! right! lines evaluated one-by-one. And I'm a 8 years-experienced developer (with a PHP background, but it doesn't really matter). Shame, shame, shame on me, how I could not see this in a first place? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I can't be certain about problem roots, but can assume it is related to file loading order. Content of `class` scope evaluated at the moment of loading file. And name `Image::THUMB_WIDTH` used before it is ever defined (and file loaded).

But still not sure, because received message is not `uninitialized constant Image`, but `uninitialized constant Image::THUMB_WIDTH`. It can related to some project details and structure which is not described in current question context.

Solution using `const_get` can be named hack (dirty, nasty hack), since you are not sure if it is ever initialized at the loading moment in current situation.

I would say this code has design issues, cause classes share responsibility and require each other at the moment of code evaluation. Maybe you should move this dependency to initialization time, for example - passing expected images parameters to `ImageUploader` while calling new? Or better to move it completely there from `Image`, since autogenerated thumb size is barely part of `Image` abstraction. It depends on `Image` class purpose, you should clarify it first.

Remember, single object - single responsibility. This way will solve dependency problem in most general and controllable way.

Answer (score 1):

Adding `require Image` at the top of `ImageUploader` does not help?

Not sure, because `Image` needs `ImageUploader`, so you might have a circular reference there.

So if that does not work, I would extract the image-configuration to another class/module. You say it belongs to the `Image` but imho it is more application-configuration, right? It specifies how images are shown/stored in this application. If you would show images in another application, it might change.

So, either you add something like `app/models/image/configuration.rb`

```
class Image
  module Configuration
    THUMB_WIDTH = 220
    PREVIEW_WIDTH = 460
    MAX_WIDTH = 960
  end
end
```

and in your `ImageUploader` you can then write

```
require `image/configuration`
```

and use `Image::Configuration::THUMB_WIDTH`.

What I generally do with such configuration properties: I put them in a `config.yml`, which I load in an initializer. It is really easy do to yourself, using something like

```
appl_config_file = "#{Rails.root}/config/config.yml"
raw_config = File.read(appl_config_file)
APP_CONFIG = HashWithIndifferentAccess.new(YAML.load(raw_config)["#{Rails.env}"])
```

or use a gem like [rails_config](https://github.com/railsjedi/rails_config).

Comment: Can I exploit `Rails::Application::Configuration` somehow?

Answer (score 1):

Keeping in mind the fact that evaluation order is very important in dynamic languages, it's best to always structure your code in a fashion that will protect you against issues like this. Consider structuring your code in the following fashion:

```
class Example
  extend Extensions
  include Inclusions
  CONSTANTS = "Should Consistently Follow"

  attr_accessor :notebook
  attr_reader :book
  attr_writer :note

  then_other_available :macro_like_methods

  def initialize; end

  def self.class_methods; end

  def instance_methods; end

  protected
    # ...
  private
    # ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source for [this RailsCasts Episode](http://railscasts.com/episodes/253-carrierwave-file-uploads), I think you should use:

```
process resize_to_limit: [model.class.const_get("THUMB_WIDTH")]
```

The benefit with this method is that you can simply declare a `THUMB_WIDTH` constant inside any other model, and then simply, use this uploader class to handle that model, as well :)

Comment: it says: `undefined local variable or method 'model'`